# How to Save Form after User Exits?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, events

When a user wants to exit, I want to show message box to it that asks,

***Do You Want to Exit?***

If the user wants to stay and selects "No", how do I save the form?

Comment: Look at the [Closing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closing?view=netcore-3.1) event.

Comment: Per the documentation, the Form.Closing event is Deprecated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closing?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Form.FormClosing()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing?view=netframework-4.8) event to detect the Closing of your Form and save the Data in there.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyForm : Form
{
    this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.FormIsClosing);
    
    private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(DialogResult.No == MessageBox.Show("Do You Want to Exit?","Close My Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information))
        {
            // Cancel the Closing event
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```